# How to resolve "FATAL EXCEPTION: main" in E/AndroidRuntime?

Tags: java, android

There is only code in fragment_main.xml. This is the error I am getting. Any suggestions?

[Click here to view the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtSRp.png)

Comment: The first suggestion is that you should post the code and error messages (not an image). You would likely benefit from visiting [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Consider [searching for this error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=FATAL%20EXCEPTION%3a%20main%20E%2fAndroidRuntime). Note also that questions are best if they are succinct - `please help!` pleading is not necessary, especially in the title.

Answer (score 0):

Your **res/drawable-v19/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml** is not existed.

Replace it with another existed one in **fragment_main.xml**